# Union Two SQL Queries

Tags: mysql, sql, join, union

I have a query like this

```
SELECT o.product_id,
       p.name,
       count(o.product_id) AS total_products_sold,
       (SELECT count(o.id)
        FROM ebay.`order` o) AS total_orders
FROM ebay.`order` o
INNER JOIN product p ON o.product_id = p.id
GROUP BY o.product_id
```

The total_orders is rerun when executed for each which not i want. I

Question:

I want the total_orders combines with every result set from the outer query.

I tried this but it only return 1 row

```
SELECT tps.product_id,
       tps.name,
       tps.total_products_sold,
       count(oo.id) AS total_orders
FROM ebay.`order` oo
INNER JOIN
  ( SELECT o.id,
           o.product_id,
           p.name,
           count(o.product_id) AS total_products_sold
   FROM ebay.`order` o
   INNER JOIN product p ON o.product_id = p.id
   GROUP BY o.product_id ) AS tps ON oo.product_id = tps.product_id
```

Any better solution ?

Thanks.

Comment: can you give sample records with your desired result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT  tps.product_id,
        tps.name,
        tps.total_products_sold,
        s.total_orders
FROM    ebay.`order` oo
        INNER JOIN
        ( 
            SELECT  o.id,
                    o.product_id,
                    p.name,
                    count(o.product_id) AS total_products_sold
            FROM    ebay.`order` o
                    INNER JOIN product p 
                        ON o.product_id = p.id
            GROUP   BY o.product_id 
        ) AS tps ON oo.product_id = tps.product_id
        CROSS JOIN
        (
            SELECT  count(id) total_orders
            FROM    ebay.`order`
        ) s
```

Comment: What is cross join ? When is the situation we use cross join ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `with rollup` which will give you the total without changing the actual query
It wont give you the result in column of every row but you will get the result of total orders in the last row.

```
SELECT 
  o.product_id,
  p.name,
  count(distinct o.id) AS totalorder
FROM 
  ebay.`order` o
INNER JOIN 
  product p 
ON 
  o.product_id = p.id
GROUP BY 
  o.product_id
WITH ROLLUP
```

For example

```
+-----------+------+------------+
| product_id| name | totalorder |
+-----------+------+------------+
|      2000 |   A  |     10     |
|      2001 |   B  |     20     |
|      NULL | NULL |     30     |   <--- Last row is having the Total order 
+-----------+------+------------+
```

### **[WITH ROLLUP](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-modifiers.html)**